# Christian children's book about journey through enchanted forest guided by king's music

Tags: identification-request

I need help identifying a children's book I remember reading years ago.

Plot: the king announces a contest for his daughter's hand in marriage. The first person to pass through the enchanted forest and arrive at the castle wins. The forest is filled with creatures that try to lead people away by mimicking various sounds. To help, the king will play his music from the castle tower (I believe it was 2 or three times a day?). The contestants must then try to recognize the king's music over the music of the creatures to find their way. Contestants are allowed to bring one other person with them; most choose strong men or soldiers.

A young man takes the king's son with him; he has the king's son play his own music while they travel so that when the king plays his music, he'll be able to recognize it and find his way to the castle.

I had read this book years ago, but have not been able to identify it. Also, there are very obvious Christian themes to this book. It is not a chapter book as far as I can recall; I believe it followed a format of full-page picture on one side and full-page text on the other for I believe at least 10 pages.

Any idea which book this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this [The Song of the King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/114456.The_Song_of_the_King) by Max Lucado?

> Carlisle, Alon, and Cassidon―known by all in the kingdom as the bravest and best knights who serve the king. But now the time has come to see who is truly worthy of the princess’s hand in marriage. As the prince tells the three knights about the king’s test, they understand the danger of the journey before them. And with only the king’s song to guide them and one companion, they must prepare for the adventure of their lives―an adventure that may cost them everything.

([description from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1433542900))

It was originally published in 1995. Amazon lists the 2014 edition as 32 pages. The same story appeared in the 1993 collection [Tell Me the Secrets](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/279382.Tell_Me_the_Secrets); it was also republished in 2000 under the title [With You All the Way](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/967667.With_You_All_the_Way).

More details from [several](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/2272136482) [reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1906883931) [on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/626916947):

- The forest is called Hemlock Forest.
- Its inhabitants are the Hopenots. They foil travelers by imitating sounds.
- The king goes to the wall of the castle three times a day to play his song on his flute.
- The prince has a matching flute and can play the same song.